# Unity entitlement check not working

Tags: c#, security, unity-game-engine, oculus, entitlements

I'm trying to publish my first app on Oculus store for Oculus GO and Gear VR, but my app is not passing though oculus entitlement check. I have written entitlement check code and it works in editor, but after I build it, code is ignored. I've already tried implementing it into some working script, but the entitlement check lines are being ignored.

Did I missed some step? I've added App ID to Oculus Platform Settings.

Comment: Please share your research and codes first.

Comment: Code is basically just the code from oculus documentation so I do not really have to share it here

Answer (score 0):

Check this it may help, he is describing how to get throw the Oculus Store Entitlement check for Unity3d builds 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqWvwe81oz8

Comment: It's best to often share content of the link as well. 
A link may die at a later point in time but the information of the question should not be lost. That is why we discourage link-only answers.